# Centering Bootstrap navbar items only on iPad portrait orientation?

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

Is it possible?

I have been trying to center the navbar items with the following media query:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav .navbar-right>li {
      display: inline-block;
      float: none;
      vertical-align: top;
}

   .navbar .navbar-collapse {
       text-align: center;
  }
}
```

I've also tried

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Make a fiddle with your code :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski http://jsfiddle.net/sLhxq16p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/sLhxq16p/3/

```
@media handheld, only screen and (min-width: 768px), only screen and (min-device-width: 768px), only screen and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .nav li {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

iPad portrait only ( iPad 3 and 4)

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
   .nav li {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

iPad portrait only (iPad 1 and 2)

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .nav li {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Bojan, however it is only centering the nav <li> in the collapsed state as far as I can see? 
My goal was to center the navbar list items in the "normal" non-collapsed state but only in portrait orientation on iPad, sorry if I was unclear.